# Centre of Gravity by integration

Tags: integration

[Solve the question to get coordinates of center of gravity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bp4Ed.jpg)

Comment: What have you done so far? Don't ask us to do your homework!

Comment: Find small change in mass 'dm'. Use mass per unit area. Then integrate.

Answer (score 0):

For $t\in \left[ 0,\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right]$,
\begin{align*}
  \frac{dx}{dt} &= -3a\cos^2 t \sin t \\
  &\le 0 \\
  \frac{dy}{dt} &=  3a\sin^2 t \cos t \\
  &\ge 0 \\
  dA &= x\, dy \\
  &= -y\, dx \\
  m &= \int \rho \, dA \\
  &= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} kxy \, x\, dy \\
  &= k\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} a^3\cos^6 t \sin^3 t \, d(a\sin^3 t) \\
  &= ka^4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 3\cos^7 t \sin^5 t \, dt \\
  &= 3ka^4 \times \frac{(3!)(2!)}{2(6!)} \\
  &= \frac{ka^4}{40} \\
  \bar{x} &=
  \frac{1}{m} \int \rho x \, dA \\
  &= \frac{1}{m} \int (kxy)(x)(-y\, dx) \\
  &= \frac{k}{m}
     \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} a^4 \cos^6 t \sin^6 t \, d(-a\cos^3 t) \\
  &= \frac{ka^5}{m}
     \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 3\cos^8 t \sin^7 t \, dt \\
  &= \frac{16ka^5}{2145m} \\
  &= \frac{128a}{429} \\
  &= \bar{y}
\end{align*}